# How to split a string with "\" using ruby?

Tags: ruby, string, split, escaping, character

Lets say I have a string:

```
str = "12345\56789"
```

How to split above string into 2 words?

```
["12345","56789"]
```

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Regexp.quote returns a string with special characters escaped. This returned string can be split with '\\'.

So the solution is: Regexp.quote('00050\00050').split('\\')[0]

Answer (score 8):

```
str = "12345/56789"
print str.split('/') # => ["12345", "56789"]
```

**Edit:** With the change to a backslash, it should be:

```
str = '12345\56789'
print str.split('\\') # => ["12345", "56789"]
```

You need the double backslash to avoid escaping the closing quote mark.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. That slash is actually "\".

Comment: @user1731249 Then use a backslash in the split.

Comment: Since the backslash wants to escape the closing quote, you'll now need to use a double backslash `('\\')`

Comment: As backslash being a escape character, ruby expects closing quote.

Comment: double backslash returns: 12345w89

Comment: Notice in my second example, the original string is using single quotes. If you're still using double quotes, you'll also need to use a double backslash here. This is because double quotes support more escape sequences. I have no idea why `\567` is generating a 'w' but it is. This is a problem with your original string, not the split method, which you can see with `puts str`.